# How to set Multipart Boundary with axios and FormData in React Native

Tags: react-native

i want to upload image by axios and FromData, while uploading image i am getting Multipart boundary not found error in response, i am not getting that where i am doing mistake any suggestions will be very helpful.

Here is my code

```
ImagePicker.showImagePicker(options, (response) => {
  console.log('Response = ', response);
  if (response.didCancel) {
    console.log('User cancelled image picker');
  } else if (response.error) {
    console.log('ImagePicker Error: ', response.error);
  } else if (response.customButton) {
    console.log('User tapped custom button: ', response.customButton);
    alert(response.customButton);
  } else {
    const source = { uri: response.uri };
    console.log('response', JSON.stringify(response));
    var photo = {
      uri: response.path,
      type: response.type,
      name: response.fileName
    };
    let formdata = new FormData();
    formdata.append('attachment',photo);
   this.imageUpload(formdata)
  }
});
```

}

Here is my imageUpload Method

```
imageUpload(formdata) {
var headers = {
  'content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'
}
var data = {
  file: formdata
}
return new Promise((resolve) => {
  axios.post(baseUrl + 'upload-media',  data ,{headers: headers}).then(response => {
    resolve(response)
    console.log(response.data)
  }).catch(err => {
    resolve(err)
    alert('Something Went Wrong')
    console.log(err.response)
  })
})
```

}

Comment: Why are you using  "uri: response.path" on photo variable instead of response.uri? Maybe that is the issue

Comment: I have been used "uri: response.uri" also but still getting same issue

Comment: Can you try axios.post without last parameter ({headers: headers})?

Comment: I am getting UnsupportedMediaTypeError after removing ({headers: headers})

Answer (score 0):

This is old but it took me a while to find the answer so if you are here...

Try two things: first, when you append your file, specify the file's name like this:

```
 formdata.append('attachment',photo, 'yourfilename.png');
```

This solved it.

Also I set the boundary in headers like this

```
headers: {
        'content-type': `multipart/form-data; boundary=${formData._boundary}`
        }
```

Comment: _boundary is undefined